# React Flux - wait for props before rendering child components

Tags: reactjs, flux

Quick and "easy": How do I make my parent component wait for a certain state to be set until I render the child component every time I access the parent (not only once)?

A bit more detailed:
I want to be able to filter results based on user input. I have a controller view "Items", that calls a child component called "FilterComponent" and passes the filter state as a prop. I make an initial call from the controller to an action creator, which gets the saved filters from local storage and dispatches them to the store. Based on that result I update the filters state and pass it as a prop to the child.

Where I'm getting stuck is finding a way to make sure that I don't render the "FilterComponent" before the filters state is set. I can get it to work, so that when I refresh the page, it loads the filters - however when I access the page somewhere else and navigate to the Items controller it just gets stuck.

I think it has something to do with the way I'm getting the filters via the action/store, which is called in componentDidMount() - since componentDidMount() is only called once and I kind of need to call it every time.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import FilterAction from '../../Actions/FilterActions';
import BaseComponent from '../../Components/Base';
import { Form, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel, InputGroup, DropdownButton, MenuItem, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Select from 'react-select';
import _ from 'lodash';

class FilterComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};

        this._bind(
            'handleExperienceChange',
            'handlePriceChange',
            'applyFilter'
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.applyFilter();
    }

    handlePriceChange(price) {
        var filter = {};
        var product = this.props.product.tag;

        filter[product] = {
            price: price ? price.value : null
        };

        let updatedState = _.merge(this.state, {
            selectedPrice: price || null
        });

        this.updateFilter(filter);

        this.setState(updatedState);
    }

    getPrice() {
        var price = this.props.lang.select.prices;
        var priceSelect = [];

        Object.keys(price).map(function (key) {
            priceSelect.push({
                value: key,
                label: price[key]
            });
        });

        return priceSelect;
    }

    applyFilter() {
        var filters = this.props.filters || null;
        var product = this.props.product || null;

        if (filters && product && filters[product.tag]) {
            var selectedPrice = filter.price ? {
                value: filter.price,
                label: this.props.lang.select.prices[filter.price]
            } : false;
        }

        var updatedState = {
            selectedPrice: selectedPrice || false
        };
        this.setState(_.merge(this.state, updatedState));
    }

    updateFilter(filter) {
        FilterAction.update(filter);
    }

    render() {
        const { product, lang } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="filter">
                <div className="flex">
                    <div className="pane-50">
                        <Select  name="price"
                                 placeholder={lang.general.form.input.price}
                                 value={this.state.selectedPrice}
                                 options={this.getPrice()}
                                 onChange={this.handlePriceChange}
                                 searchable={false} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FilterComponent;
```

Comment: Can you not just check for the existence of this state in the `Items` render method, and only include the `FilterComponent` as a child if the state is set? Like (in jsx) `{this.state.filters ? <FilterComponent {...this.state} /> : 'Loading...'}`

Comment: Thanks for your response Bill! It works when I do a browser refresh on that particular page, but it gets stuck with no errors on 'Loading...' when I enter the page somewhere else and navigate to the items page. Maybe my child component is the problem? I've updated my answer and included the code of my child component. What I have also noticed is that when I hit refresh, it calls render() in the parent 3 times, and the third one has the filters set, however when I navigate from another page to it, it only renders twice and both times filters is undefined.

Comment: Your code seems to be mixing and matching `this.props.filters` and `this.state.filters` in a way that doesn't make sense to me.  In `updateFilters` you set `this.state.filters` but you never actually use that state anywhere; you use `this.props.filters` in `applyFilter`.  Could that be your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Bill, the example is my child component and it relies only on `this.props.filters` (see `applyFilters()`). The filters state in`updateFilters` is no longer used as I now save any updated filter into the storage directly, so please ignore that bit (I have removed it from the code above). I have now removed the FilterComponent from the parent completely and it's still stuck on 'Loading...'. I think the `ChangeListener` only works on a full page reload.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any errors? Variable `filter` seems undefined in your `applyFilter()`.

Also, although unrelated, you can set state by calling `setState()` with the new keys and values, don't have to create the entire new state:

Instead of:

```
var updatedState = {
    selectedPrice: selectedPrice || false
};
this.setState(_.merge(this.state, updatedState));
```

You can simply do:

```
this.setState({
    selectedPrice: selectedPrice || false
});
```

Lastly, consider calling `applyFilter()` from `componentWillMount()` since it affects how the component is rendered. `componentWillMount()` is called before `render()`.

To get faster help, consider creating a simplified, isolated, but working example of your project on codepen or similar services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply squall3d! I seem to have figured out what the problem was. I had called my action creator for getting existing filters before the`ChangeListener`, which caused it to fail to listening to changes from the store. I also had to use `componentDidUpdate()` within my`FilterComponent`, to make sure it re-renders when I switch products and not just on a full page reload. In regards to your suggestion calling `applyFilter` from `render()` - I thought it was bad practice calling anything that changes state within `render()`?

Comment: Ah that's right, misread it with the poor formatting on my mobile. I'll remove that nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If your state isn't ready, just return null from your render() method. Whenever state or props is updated, render() will run again. Once your state is ready, return your child components as normal.

```
render() {
    const { product, lang } = this.props;

    if (!this.state.selectedPrice)
      return null;

    return (
        <div className="filter">
            <div className="flex">
                <div className="pane-50">
                    <Select  name="price"
                             placeholder={lang.general.form.input.price}
                             value={this.state.selectedPrice}
                             options={this.getPrice()}
                             onChange={this.handlePriceChange}
                             searchable={false} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```